# What happens with an interrupted upload to UbuntuOne?

Tags: ubuntu-one, upload

I have uploaded 465M of a 677M folder to Ubuntu One. But it stopped for some reason.

How do I continue the upload to complete the file please. Bandwidth very limited.

Comment: Is the upload being handled via the desktop client, or via the web?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you just have to reconnect your PC to your internet connection and let ubuntu one finish the upload. I mean that ubuntu one is able to continue an interrupted upload process, so you don't need to wait again for the 677 MB, but only for the remaining 212 MB.